# Kivy: Updating Line in KV Lang from Python Code

Tags: python, kivy

I cannot seem to get the canvas line to update when the button is pressed and the data is updated. The online guide only shows the kv lang side of this issue, so I am presuming the issue lies in the python code.

this is the kv lang:

```
<Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, .3, .8, .5
        Line:
            points: self.data

    Button:
        text: 'Generate'
        size_hint: (0.15, 0.1)
        pos_hint: {'x':0.4, 'y':0.4}
        on_press: root.btn()
```

this is the python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
kivy.require('1.11.1')


class Screen(FloatLayout):

    data = []

    def __init__(self, i=0, data=[0, 0, 0, 0]):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = i
        Screen.data = data

    def btn(self):
        print('Generate')
        Screen.data = [10*self.i, 10*self.i, 100*self.i, 100*self.i]
        self.i = self.i + 1
        print(Screen.data)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `Line` to update whenever the `points` are updated, you need make it a `ListProperty`, like this:

```
class Screen(FloatLayout):

    data = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, i=0, data=[0, 0, 0, 0]):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = i

    def btn(self):
        print('Generate')
        self.data = [10*self.i, 10*self.i, 100*self.i, 100*self.i]
        self.i = self.i + 1
        print(self.data)
```

And you must refer to it as `self.data`, not `Screen.data`, because it is a property of the instance.